# How to use forEach() method for iterating AWS Reserved EC2 Instances by Java 8?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, java-8

I found this code to describe ec2 instances in AWS SDK for java. I need to convert this code snippet to Java 8 by using `forEach()` method.
I know how to use `forEach()` method for iterate a single list. But I'm struggling with this code since it is nested.

```
 DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
    while(!done) {
        DescribeInstancesResult response = ec2.describeInstances(request);

        for(Reservation reservation : response.getReservations()) {
            for(Instance instance : reservation.getInstances()) {
                    String instanceID = instance.getInstanceId(),
                    return instanceID;                    
            }
        }
```

What I want is to iterate through all the instances and get the `instanceID` for further use by java 8. Can somebody give me a tip to fulfill my requirement? It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Tip: You are looking for `flatMap` and `findFirst` APIs of [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code from the question can be refactored to use `Optional`, `Stream` and `flatMap` instead of nested loop

```
private final AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.defaultClient();

private Optional<String> findFirstEC2InstanceId() {
  DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();

  return ec2.describeInstances(request).getReservations()
            .stream()
            .map(Reservation::getInstances)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .findFirst()
            .map(Instance::getInstanceId);
}
```

The method can be used in the following way to print an instance ID

```
findFirstEC2InstanceId().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Returning an `Instance` object instead of `String` ID is even more flexible

```
private Optional<Instance> firstEC2Instance() {
  DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();

  return ec2.describeInstances(request).getReservations()
            .stream()
            .map(Reservation::getInstances)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .findFirst();
}
```

Then we can get instance ID or any other data the following way

```
firstEC2Instance().map(Instance::getInstanceId).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code using java 8 stream

```
DescribeInstanceResult response = ec2.describeInstances(request);

String instanceId = response.getReservations()
                            .stream()
                            .flatMap(reservation -> reservation.getInstances()
                                                               .stream())
                            .findFirst()
                            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But it gives a compilation error saying that `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Instance> to Stream<? extends Object>`. Anyway i'll try to fix the isse with this snippet you posted.

Comment: sry i did a small mistake..i edited my code can you try now

Comment: Should the type of instanceId be Instance?

Comment: now what is the issue.. no because we are getting the instanceId which is String from Instance Object..that's what you post your question returning a instance id

Comment: It gives the compile issue, `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Instance to String`. I'm totally new to flatMap and findFirst in Stream API. I'll research that. For the time being, can you give me a hint to resolve this issue?

Comment: Shouldn'i i be using the .getInstanceId() method to get the id?

Comment: I'd suggest to use `Optional<String> instanceId = ...findFirst();`. Dealing with nullables is one of the top sources for stupid and hard to find bugs. If you use `Optional` the compiler forces you to care for possible _null_ values where needed.